# Почему вызывается метод из класса A?

Tags: java, ооп

Здравствуйте!

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в данном коде вызывается метод из класса A, логично ведь, что должен вызваться B.

```
public class App2 {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        A a = new B();
        a.method (2.0);
    }
}
class A{
    void method(Number n) {
        System.out.println ("Number");
    }
}

class B extends A{

    void method(Double a){
        System.out.println ("DOUBLE");
    }
}
```

Comment: 
        ((B)a).method (2.0); а если так?

Comment: Так работает, как ожидалось, но я все равно не понимаю, почему в моем варианте не так. =)

Comment: ранние, позднее связывание?

Comment: мм, точнее можно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ранние, позднее связывание?

Не в этом суть. Суть в том, что Java не поддерживает [ковариантность аргументов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29#Java) при наследовании. Поскольку `B` наследует `А`, и `Double` наследует `Number`, метод `method()` в дочернем классе `B` не перекрывает родительский. В противном случае это нарушало бы [принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Представьте, что у вас есть еще класс `C` такого вида:

```
class С extends A{

    void method(Integer a){
        System.out.println ("INTEGER");
    }
}
```

Поскольку `Integer` унаследован от `Number`, такое объявление тоже было бы ковариантным по аргументу. Теперь мысленно попробуем выполнить код:

```
A a = new С();
a.method (2.0);
```

И тут бы возникла неувязка. С точки зрения класса А аргумент 2.0 адекватен, а с точки зрения класса С - нет. Поэтому для обеспечения безопасности типов Java не позволяет перекрывать родительские методы в дочерних классах таким образом.

Comment: а если аргументы методов одинаковые?

Comment: Если бы аргументы и в классе `A` и в классе `B` были одного типа, то отработало бы перекрытие и код

    A a = new B();
    a.method (2.0);

вывел бы на экран слово `DOUBLE`

Comment: а если константы, а не методы?

Comment: Большое спасибо, достаточно ясно и понятно объяснили